# Remove outliners pandas through groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a simple function that removes outliners and returns a new DataFrame:

```
def remove_outliner(df):
   df.index = df.time
   df['median']= df['price'].rolling(15).median()
   df['std'] = df['price'].rolling(15).std()
   df["std+"] = df['median']+3*df['std']
   df["std-"] = df['median']-3*df['std']
   #filter setup
   df2 = df[(df.price <= df['median']+3*df['std']) &
            (df.price >= df['median']-3*df['std'])]
   return df2
```

Is there a way to apply such a function using groupby? So something like this (pseudo code):

```
df.groupby(["product"]).filter(remove_outliner).concat_groups()
```

My naive approach would be to iterate over the groups. Save them in a list and then apply pd.concat. But I hope there is a more elegant way. Thanks a lot for any hint!

PS: Example Input

```
                               product price 
          2014-08-25 01:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 02:00:00  B       7.2
          2014-08-25 03:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 04:00:00  B       7.2
          2014-08-25 04:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 05:00:00  A       99.2
          2014-08-25 06:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 06:00:00  B       7.2
          2014-08-25 21:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 22:00:00  B       88.2
```

Expected Result

```
                               product price 
          2014-08-25 01:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 02:00:00  B       7.2
          2014-08-25 03:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 04:00:00  B       7.2
          2014-08-25 04:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 06:00:00  A       1.2
          2014-08-25 06:00:00  B       7.2
          2014-08-25 21:00:00  A       1.2
```

If the first rows would disappear that would be fine. The remove_outliner function adds some columns but they could be deleted. Since different products might have different price scales, I can't apply the filter just on the price and need to work with groups.

Comment: Did you try the plain `df.groupby(["product"]).filter(remove_outliner)`? What's wrong?

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I added an example.

Comment: @QuangHoang It doesn't work this way since filter expects a boolean input

Comment: I mean `apply`: `df.groupby(["product"]).apply(remove_outliner)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang That looks really good. It returns a DataFrame with a MultiIndex (for each product). So still struggling to remove the MultiIndex and resort on time.

Comment: Just use `reset_index` to resolve each level at a time. You may also want `groupby('product', group_keys=False)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried modified your function a bit (you probably don't want `median` and `std` in your dataframe):

```
def remove_outliner(df):
    roll_median= df['price'].rolling(15).median()
    roll_std = df['price'].rolling(15).std()

    #filter setup
    df2 = df[(df.price.le(roll_median + 3*roll_std) &
            (df.price.ge(roll_median - 3*roll_std)]

    return df2

# set_index here, not inside the function:
df.set_index('time').groupby('product', group_keys=False).apply(remove_outliner)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the solution. Learned something new! Not aware of group_keys=False. Also just had to add a sort to restore the order. sort_index()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_wo_outliers = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

There is also a nice article which talks about [detecting and treating outliers](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba).

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is basically the same what the remove_outliner function does. But it must be applied to different groups in my case.

Comment: True. While your function specifies the columns, I am applying the solution to the entire dataframe.